# Regex Expression for duplicated commas within string

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a comma separated string which looks like the below:

> **,,0**,2,7,9,10,11,4,4,24,**25,,5**3,5,3,5,6,4,6,463,6,63,4,53,46,346,4,36,346,34,6,36,34,6,364,**7,,63**,32,14,**2,,**

My current regex is: `@"^[0-9,]*(?<=[0-9])$"` - I am using this within ASP.Net Core

I need to include matching of duplicated commas within the string, at the beginning, end and within the string itself. As an example I have highlighted the commas in bold.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about `7,,63`? And why can't you just use `,,` for the regex?

Comment: Try `^(?:,+)?[0-9]+(?:,+[0-9]+)*,*$` or `^,{0,2}[0-9]+(?:,{1,2}[0-9]+)*,{0,2}$`

Comment: @Nick - Yes sorry, I need to match on that too. I have tried the regex's provided and does not seem to validate how I am expecting. The code I am using for this is `        //[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9,]*(?<=[0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "Field must be sites seperated by a comma with no spaces.")]` - The requirement is to validate against a string input which contains a list of numbers, separated by comma however validation must fail if the string contains double commans ",," in any part of the string. The input string can also only end with a number and as such can not end with a comma. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

this may help you:

```regex
^(?:(,)*[0-9]+)*(,)*
```

Comment: Why capture groups for comma? That slow down the process.

Answer (score 1):

Seem to have stumbled upon something which works. Thanks for your assistance.

What works for me is below in case it helps anyone else.

```
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*
```

Comment: You may accept your own answer if it fits your needs.